# ElementRef is losing its value after getting called second time from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am facing a weird issue with the ElementRef in Angular 5.
I have a home component which contains two popups, which consists of different component ListPopUp and tile. I am iterating through a list and creating multiple tiles on the home page. When you click on a tile it will open a listPopup.

From the list popUp you can click a function that will trigger a event in Parent and thus trigger a function in tile component.

Everything works file except when we trigger the function second time the myBar ElementRef (in tile component class) returns undefined. I have tried accessing the bar directly using getElementById("myBar") but it also becomes undefined the second time. I am not sure why this is happening, I have tried to modify the code and look for any explanation in Angular documentation but nothing is helping.

I have provided the code for all the three components.

Please let me know if further info is required.

Here is the code:

TileComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tile',
  templateUrl: 'tile.html'
})
export class TileComponent {
  @Input('tileinfo') tileinfo;
  @ViewChild('myBar') myBar:ElementRef;

  constructor() {

  };

  ngOnInit() {

  };

  move(value) {
    let elem = this.myBar;
    let id = setInterval(frame, this.tileinfo.progressSpeed * 1000);
    this.tileinfo.active = value;
    let val = this.tileinfo;
    val.allowNext = false;
    function frame() {
      if (val.progress >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        delete val.active;
        val.allowNext = true;
        val.progress = 0;
      } else {
        val.progress++;
        elem.nativeElement.style.width = val.progress + '%';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

HomeComponent Code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { GlobalProvider } from '../../providers/global/global';
import { CommonMethodsProvider } from '../../providers/common-methods/common-methods';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('tileComponent') tileComponent: any;
  tileInfoArr: Array<any> = [];
  ageList: Array<any> = [];
  gameObject: any;
  modalInfo: any = {};
  modalList: any = {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private globalService: GlobalProvider, private commonService: CommonMethodsProvider) {
    this.globalService.getGameDummy().subscribe(data => this.gameSetupHelper(data), error => console.log(error));
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  fillTiles() {
    this.tileInfoArr = [
      {
        name: 'Research',
        progress: 1,
        description: "Description Here",
        progressSpeed: this.gameObject.researchProgress,
        allowNext: true,
      },
    ];
  }

  tileClicked(tileInfo) {
    switch (tileInfo.name) {
      case 'Research':
        if (this.tileInfoArr[0].allowNext)
        this.modalList = this.commonService.generateModalList("Research List", this.globalService.getAgeDataObj().researchList);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  listItemClicked(stuff) {
    if (stuff.data === "age") {
      this.tileComponent.move(this.gameObject.nextAgeDisplayName);
    } else {
      this.tileComponent.move(stuff.data.name);
    }
  };

}
```

ListPopupComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'list-popup',
  templateUrl: 'list-popup.html'
})
export class ListPopupComponent {
  @Input('modalList') modalList;
  @Output() listItemClicked = new EventEmitter();

  text: string;

  constructor() {

  };

  startStuff(listItem): void {
    this.listItemClicked.emit({
      data: listItem
    });
  }

  closePopup() {
    this.modalList.showPopup = false;
  };

}
```

HTML :
HomeComponent:

```
 <div padding style="padding-top: 0px">
    <div class="tile-container-container">
      <div class="tile-container" *ngFor="let tileinfo of tileInfoArr;">
        <tile [tileinfo]="tileinfo" (click)="tileClicked(tileinfo)" #tileComponent></tile>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<info-popup [modalInfo]="modalInfo"></info-popup>
<list-popup (listItemClicked) = "listItemClicked($event)" [modalList]="modalList"></list-popup>
```

TileHTML:

```
<div class="tile-box">
  <div class="tile-inside">
    <h6>
      {{tileinfo.name}}
    </h6>
    <p>
      {{tileinfo.description}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer *ngIf="tileinfo.progress !== 0">
    <div id="myProgress">
      <div id="myBar" #myBar></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

ListPopupHTML

```
<div *ngIf="modalList.showPopup" id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content card">
    <span class="close" (click)="closePopup()">
     x
    </span>
    <div>
      <h6>
        {{modalList.title}}
      </h6>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div *ngIf="modalList.list && modalList.list.length > 0;else ageChange">
      <ul class="list">
        <li  class="item" (click)="startStuff(listInfo)" *ngFor="let listInfo of modalList.list; index as i; even as isEven; odd as isOdd" class="">
          <div>
            <span class="">{{listInfo.name}}</span>
            <br>
            <span>{{listInfo.description}}</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ng-template #ageChange>
      <div class="age-Change">
        <h1>
          Enter New Age
        </h1>        
        <div (click)="startStuff('age')" class="new-age-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one question. Your referencing `tileComponent` in `HomeComponent` via `ViewChild` method. But as I can see there can be more than one `tileComponent` at once? So the correct way to access `tileComponent` would be via `ViewChildren`?

Comment: @SplitterAlex thanks for pointing that out, you are right it should be ViewChildren. But the issue is still there even if I change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Silliest mistake that cost me a day of work.

Using `*ngIf="tileinfo.progress !== 0"` in the tile template. and then making `val.progress = 0;` in tileComponet. This was removing the div at the end thus the element was not coming because there was no element at all.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time, who took time to look into the issue...